# Symfony2 - How to populated a select field with a very large amount of data (nearly 40.000)

Tags: forms, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony 2. I have so far 2 bundles. The first bundle is a called UserBundle and is build using FosUserBundle. The second bundle is called GeoBundle and contains one entity called France which's table contain almost 40.000 records. Each record refers to a city with postal code, regional code.... Basically I use this entity in my user registration form so that the user can select an appropriate city from the list. By the way I use an Entity Field Type to do  that.

My problem is that everything is working fine with just a few records in the table but with the almost 40.000 records the page where my form is, is not even opening. I already extended my memory in php.ini to 256M and more but the page is still not opening.

So my question is simple. What would be the best solution to populate a select field with that many records? I am of course open to other solutions. Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: Is there a way you can narrow the results? Can you ask for a zip first, then ajax load the relevant cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably best using an autocomplete field. You can find plenty of solutions on Google.  Or try a bundle like https://github.com/shtumi/ShtumiUsefulBundle

Comment: Thank you for the reply Mike. I am on my way to check this out and I will revert...

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't load the full list, that would be bad for your server, your bandwidth and for the memory required by the client (if it's a mobile browser, forget it!)

I suggest to use **jQuery UI Autocomplete**, this is a jQuery plug-in that can load the elements required via Ajax from your server, so you don't have to load the hole thing. It's also well tested and easy to implement.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am about to compare the two propositions and will revert...

Answer (score 1):

Try using this Symfony2 bundle.

https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/jquery/autocomplete/text.md

This is very helful and in Symfony2. It will save your time and have a look at its other extensions